# Android Preference menu(change array id when clicked)

Tags: android, arrays, spinner, preference

i got 2 classes. A class with a spinner in it and a preference class. The spinner is set up with a array from strings.xml` s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.height_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter1);`
```

The second class is the preference class with a ListPreference(think it is a a ListPreference)
/kind of a spinner. If u click it and select any of the items from the ListPreference i want the spinner to use another array. Change R.array.height_array to R.array.height2_array or something like that. Possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, something like this should work. If you need more than 2 choices, use more ifs

```
if (prefs == choiceOne){
ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.height_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s1.setAdapter(adapter1);
}else{
ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.height2_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
s1.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
```